# CSS - list element gets pushed out of position by :before directive

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a problem with an HTML list which I am endeavouring to style with CSS.

The problem is that I want to use the `:before` pseudo-element to style my list element so that I can do something like this:

```
   |- Item 1
   |- Item 2
   |- Item four
```

To this end I am using a bit of CSS where I use the `:before` directive to add a bit of style ahead of each entry. The source code looks a bit like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <!-- and so on -->
</ul>
```

Styled thus:

```
li:before 
{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2em;
    height: 1em;
    position: relative;
    background-color: orange;

}
```

This works as expected, however when I get a long list item, I get an outcome like this:

```
|- Item 1
|- Item 2
|- Item four number four fourth item item
 the fourth and so on.
```

I couldn't see a way to avoid this, so I placed my item content into a `span` so I could block it out like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><span class='li-content'>Short content</span></li>
  <li><span class='li-content'>Long content long content long content long content long content</span></li>
   <li><span class='li-content'>Short content</span></li>
</ul>
```

My complete stylesheet looks like this:

```
ul 
{
   width: 20em;
   list-style-type: none;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   padding: 1em;
}
li
{
   clear: both;
}
li:before 
{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2em;
    height: 1em;
    position: relative;
    background-color: orange;

}
.li-content
{
     display: inline-block;
   /* position: absolute; */
}
```

But now I have a problem where if I make the position `relative` I get this:

```
|- Short content
|-
 Long content long content long content 
 long content
|- Short content
```

Whereas if I make the position `absolute` they align correctly with the `:before` selector, but the long content just appears directly over the next list item, turning the letters into a confusing jumble. There is a [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9sra7jfx/).

Tweaking other style components ( for example `float`ing everything ) does not seem to prevent one of these two behaviours occurring. The closest thing I have found is to set the `max-width` on the content span while it is configured for `block` display but then my `:before` block for some reason sinks to the bottom.

```
|- Short content
   Long content long content long content 
|- long content
|- Short content
```

What can I do to create the situation where I have my "before" block prior to the content of my text and my text remains indented right of the block no matter how many lines of text I have in my list item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use absolute positioning on the pseudo element and margin-left on the span

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9sra7jfx/4/)

**CSS**

```
ul 
{
   width: 20em;
   list-style-type: none;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   padding: 1em;
}
li {
   clear: both;
   position: relative;
}
li:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 2em;
    height: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: orange;

}
.li-content {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2.5em; /* approx based on width of :before - YMMV */
}
```